# How to manually set a single bean property with Jackson?

Tags: jackson, jax-rs, javabeans

I'm trying to manually update a bean (it is an argument to a JAX-RS resource method).  The value of the field to be set in the bean is to be deserialized from JSON, contextually.

I want to do:

```
       ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
       // .... <configured, ClassIntrospector obtained for type> ...
       BeanProperty prop;
       // ... <bean property resolved through ClassIntrospector> ...
       AnnotatedMember mutator = prop.getMutator();
       JsonFactory jf = new JsonFactory();
       JsonParser parser = jf.createParser(textProp);
       Object value = objectMapper.getDeserializationContext().readValue(parser, mutator.getRawType());
       mutator.setValue(beanInstance, value);
```

The problem is that Jackson is throwing a `NullPointerException`:

```
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.getTypeFactory(DeserializationContext.java:251)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.readValue(DeserializationContext.java:758)
```

I confirmed with the debugger that the `_config` field of my `DeserializationContext` is `null`, and that this is what is being accessed during my code sequence.

So, what gives?   How can I configure this properly so that this works?  (Or is there some other way to manually deserialize a JSON fragment to a given type, respecting the JAX-RS resource context / classes?)

Comment: I should add that this is not in a container of any kind - I'm using the client side Jersey features and my entry point is a J2SE `main(String[])` function.

Comment: And also that of course I checked my object mapper is configured - `objectMapper.getDeserializationConfig()` returns a valid, non-null object.